# How to add php variable inside wc_enqueue_js('jQuery') function?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, jquery

```
wc_enqueue_js('
    jQuery("img:not([title!=\"\"][title])").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("title", jQuery(this).attr(<?php get_the_id() ?>));
})          
');
```

Like this. how to add `<?php get_the_id() ?>` inside wc_enqueue_js.

Comment: You can do that by string concatenation instead, e.g. `' . get_the_id() . '`, plus escaping if you weren't writing a number, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do: do you actually want to look up the product titles from somewhere? That's not the code you've written.

Comment: I see clearly your question, but If you need to send some php data to js script - you can do this more natively with wordpress wp_localize_script function. If you need an example, just let me know